# Paho GO client unable to connect to Broker

Tags: go, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm trying to connect to a mosquitto broker which is using certificate based authentication.

The mosquitto snipped configuration below:

```
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key

require_certificate true
```

The configuration it works because I'm able to make a pub/sub in a remote machine using following commands:

```
mosquitto_pub -t "/test" -m "test" --cafile ca/ca.crt --cert certs/client.crt --key certs/client.key -p 8883 -h server.com

mosquitto_sub -t "/test" --cafile ca/ca.crt --cert certs/client.crt --key certs/client.key -p 8883 -h server.com
```

or open a SSL socket by:

```
openssl s_client -connect server.com:8883 -CAfile ca/ca.crt -cert certs/client.crt -key certs/client.key
```

but when I trying to use GO Paho client doesn't work:

The the configuration loading doesn't work because in `configureMqttConnection()` is unable to load the Certificates (this line `tls.LoadX509KeyPair(c.config.CertFile, c.config.KeyFile)`) and in `connect(backOff int)` fails because the client is unable to send the certificate in the handshake.

I think maybe the problem is that the certificates that LoadX509KeyPair is expecting are not the ones I'm generating. My certificates says 'BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE' and not being trusted and certificated or something like this. If this is I not sure how I can create the correct certificate.

I'm using this GO code below (the code starts with `GO start()`:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "time"

    MQTT "git.eclipse.org/gitroot/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.golang.git"
    "linksmart.eu/lc/core/catalog"
    "linksmart.eu/lc/core/catalog/service"
)

// MQTTConnector provides MQTT protocol connectivity
type MQTTConnector struct {
    config        *MqttProtocol
    clientID      string
    client        *MQTT.Client
    pubCh         chan AgentResponse
    subCh         chan<- DataRequest
    pubTopics     map[string]string
    subTopicsRvsd map[string]string // store SUB topics "reversed" to optimize lookup in messageHandler
}

const defaultQoS = 1

func (c *MQTTConnector) start() {
    logger.Println("MQTTConnector.start()")

    if c.config.Discover && c.config.URL == "" {
        err := c.discoverBrokerEndpoint()
        if err != nil {
            logger.Println("MQTTConnector.start() failed to start publisher:", err.Error())
            return
        }
    }

    // configure the mqtt client
    c.configureMqttConnection()

    // start the connection routine
    logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.start() Will connect to the broker %v\n", c.config.URL)
    go c.connect(0)

    // start the publisher routine
    go c.publisher()
}

// reads outgoing messages from the pubCh und publishes them to the broker
func (c *MQTTConnector) publisher() {
    for resp := range c.pubCh {
        if !c.client.IsConnected() {
            logger.Println("MQTTConnector.publisher() got data while not connected to the broker. **discarded**")
            continue
        }
        if resp.IsError {
            logger.Println("MQTTConnector.publisher() data ERROR from agent manager:", string(resp.Payload))
            continue
        }
        topic := c.pubTopics[resp.ResourceId]
        c.client.Publish(topic, byte(defaultQoS), false, resp.Payload)
        // We dont' wait for confirmation from broker (avoid blocking here!)
        //<-r
        logger.Println("MQTTConnector.publisher() published to", topic)
    }
}


func (c *MQTTConnector) stop() {
    logger.Println("MQTTConnector.stop()")
    if c.client != nil && c.client.IsConnected() {
        c.client.Disconnect(500)
    }
}

func (c *MQTTConnector) connect(backOff int) {
    if c.client == nil {
        logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.connect() client is not configured")
        return
    }
    for {
        logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.connect() connecting to the broker %v, backOff: %v sec\n", c.config.URL, backOff)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(backOff) * time.Second)
        if c.client.IsConnected() {
            break
        }
        token := c.client.Connect()
        token.Wait()
        if token.Error() == nil {
            break
        }
        logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.connect() failed to connect: %v\n", token.Error().Error())
        if backOff == 0 {
            backOff = 10
        } else if backOff <= 600 {
            backOff *= 2
        }
    }

    logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.connect() connected to the broker %v", c.config.URL)
    return
}

func (c *MQTTConnector) onConnected(client *MQTT.Client) {
    // subscribe if there is at least one resource with SUB in MQTT protocol is configured
    if len(c.subTopicsRvsd) > 0 {
        logger.Println("MQTTPulbisher.onConnected() will (re-)subscribe to all configured SUB topics")

        topicFilters := make(map[string]byte)
        for topic, _ := range c.subTopicsRvsd {
            logger.Printf("MQTTPulbisher.onConnected() will subscribe to topic %s", topic)
            topicFilters[topic] = defaultQoS
        }
        client.SubscribeMultiple(topicFilters, c.messageHandler)
    } else {
        logger.Println("MQTTPulbisher.onConnected() no resources with SUB configured")
    }
}

func (c *MQTTConnector) onConnectionLost(client *MQTT.Client, reason error) {
    logger.Println("MQTTPulbisher.onConnectionLost() lost connection to the broker: ", reason.Error())

    // Initialize a new client and reconnect
    c.configureMqttConnection()
    go c.connect(0)
}

func (c *MQTTConnector) configureMqttConnection() {
    connOpts := MQTT.NewClientOptions().
        AddBroker(c.config.URL).
        SetClientID(c.clientID).
        SetCleanSession(true).
        SetConnectionLostHandler(c.onConnectionLost).
        SetOnConnectHandler(c.onConnected).
        SetAutoReconnect(false) // we take care of re-connect ourselves

    // Username/password authentication
    if c.config.Username != "" && c.config.Password != "" {
        connOpts.SetUsername(c.config.Username)
        connOpts.SetPassword(c.config.Password)
    }

    // SSL/TLS
    if strings.HasPrefix(c.config.URL, "ssl") {
        tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}
        // Custom CA to auth broker with a self-signed certificate
        if c.config.CaFile != "" {
            caFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(c.config.CaFile)
            if err != nil {
                logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.configureMqttConnection() ERROR: failed to read CA file %s:%s\n", c.config.CaFile, err.Error())
            } else {
                tlsConfig.RootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()
                ok := tlsConfig.RootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(caFile)
                if !ok {
                    logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.configureMqttConnection() ERROR: failed to parse CA certificate %s\n", c.config.CaFile)
                }
            }
        }
        // Certificate-based client authentication
        if c.config.CertFile != "" && c.config.KeyFile != "" {
            cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(c.config.CertFile, c.config.KeyFile)
            if err != nil {
                logger.Printf("MQTTConnector.configureMqttConnection() ERROR: failed to load client TLS credentials: %s\n",
                    err.Error())
            } else {
                tlsConfig.Certificates = []tls.Certificate{cert}
            }
        }

        connOpts.SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig)
    }

    c.client = MQTT.NewClient(connOpts)
}
```

I think the problem i

Answer (score 2):

Certificates that start `BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE` is an OpenSSL "trusted certificate" file which is a format not understood/parsable by the Go crypto libraries. When you generated the cert did you use any of the options under "TRUST SETTINGS" on the [x509 man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/apps/x509.html)?
The Go TLS library is just [looking](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/tls.go?s=6279:6292#L204) for `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` at the start of the file, anything else will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks. If you write how to create the correct cert I give you the cookie